# jQuery: When to query new outer height after CSS change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, outerheight

If I do

```
var theHeight;
element.css('min-height', h);
theHeight = element.outerHeight();
```

in Chrome I get the **old** outer height.

I have to do

```
var theHeight;
element.css('min-height', h);
setTimeout(function() {
  theHeight = element.outerHeight();
}, 1);
```

instead (or, of course, anything which produces a similar effect) to make `outerHeight` report the "correct" height (which I expect to be the persisting real height we can see after changing `min-height`).

**Unfortunately, `setTimeout` is not an option for me. What can I use instead? It should work in all major browsers (current versions).**

Comment: `setTimeout` might be your best option

Comment: Does `element` have `height` set?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. I was getting the correct height. I used Chrome itself

Comment: @Zlatev: No `height` set, and `h` has the value `''` which makes the former effect of `min-height` disappear.

Comment: @ideaboxer so your intention is to remove the min height?

Comment: @Reddy: I can't set `height`. `min-height` is crucial, because otherwise a possibly growing content was not able to spread the element.

Comment: @Reddy: Yes, I remove `min-height` and afterwards measure the real size of the element (which depends on its actual content).

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it brother, check this http://imgur.com/m6bZTWL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107202/discussion-between-ideaboxer-and-reddy).

Comment: Is using ```'auto'``` as your ```h``` value an option? Seems to do the job. https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/k2nvpvd2/

Comment: Using `'auto'` must have the same effect as removing the minimum height completely, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is **NOT** your best option.

What you want to do is apply some javascript after the DOM has loaded (CSS is applied before document.ready).

You can do easily with [JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  modifySomeDomElement();
});
```

[docs here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

I hope this helps,

Rhys